# Azure Devops> Run Test Plan: Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException

Tags: azure-devops, automated-tests

Added a Run tests task to a pipeline. Tests pass, but the log shows the below error:

> Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.ObjectModel.TestPlatformException: Unable to find **\obj\release\netcoreapp2.2\myProject.deps.json. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk".

[image]
The project does have the nuget package for the `Test.Sdk`.
What do I miss here? Thank you.

Comment: Did you get a chance to try out below answer? Please let me know how did it go? We can discuss it to work out a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

The error said myProject.deps.json is missing from folder "\obj\release..". This folder contains the output files of dotnet build,which doesnot have file myProject.deps.json. You might need to point the `vstest search folder` to the published folder of dotnet publish task.

You can add an output arguments (`-o $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)`) for your **dotnet publish task** to specifically publish to a folder.

For below example the output files are published to $(build.artifactstagingdirectory) which has file myProject.deps.json.

[image]

Then in your vstest task, you can specify the test **search folder** to `$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)` 
[image]